# Where do I find a terminal lens for Unity?

Tags: unity, command-line, software-recommendation, lenses

[image: Mock-up of what a terminal lens could look like]

I have been googling for a terminal lens, i.e. a Unity lens that <strike>integrates the terminal into the usual dash</strike> replaces the current <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> functionality.

For instance one could have a line of icons as it currently is, with command history sensitive to the typed word, and below that terminal output. All I could find on this were stale old posts in the Ubuntu Forums and an old brainstorm.

Does anyone know of a working terminal lens for Unity, like my **mock-up above**?

Comment: ask Jorge in chat ;) http://novatillasku.com/2011/05/18/unity-terminal-lens-mockup-jorge-castro/

Comment: Thx Rinz, no Mr. Castro in chat so far. If you seem him, be so kind, and point him to my question.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently nothing that does exactly what it pictured above since, at the moment, a lens cannot define a content area like the one pictured in order to display (and update) the output of a command.

It is possible to press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run commands from the overlay which appears.  However, it is not possible to observe terminal output from commands run from this overlay.

Another option is to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> as a shortcut to open a terminal window.

Comment: Which gives me the idea that sort of lens could fully replace the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> functuonality. One could have one line of command history/search results (same style as currently displayed when pressing the key combination) and full blown terminal output a little bit below (as in my picture).